# Accessing a label defined locally

Tags: ios, uilabel

My app has a method that creates a label

```
     -(void)addLabel:(float)x:(float)y:(float)w:(float)h:(NSString *)text {
        CGRect label1Frame = CGRectMake( x, y, w, h );
        UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: label1Frame];
        label1.text = text;
        [self.view addSubview:label1];}
```

Then I call this method from other methods.

How can I access one of these labels to remove it from the superview, as I don't have an var name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)addLabel:(float)x :(float)y :(float)w :(float)h :(NSString *)text tag:(NSInteger)tag {
    CGRect label1Frame = CGRectMake( x, y, w, h );
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: label1Frame];
    label1.tag = tag;
    label1.text = text;
    [self.view addSubview:label1];
}
```

Then pass in an appropriate `tag` value (an integer) which is unique. Then use:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:someIntID];
```

to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ivar/property to it. If you dont want to have this label on your interface, declare a class extension inside your implementation file and declare your label

```
@interface yourclass()
@property (nonatomic, weak)UILabel *yourLabel;
@end
```

Remember to add your @synthesize to your implementation file. Assign the value to the property after adding the label as a subview.

Comment: you don't **need to**. Also, it pretty much seems that the method of OP is a factory method - so the number of labels is dynamically decided at runtime, and so you can't easily add properties at compile time (you can actually add properties dynamically, using the Objective-C runtime, but's that quite a big deal).